# Get package version of file

Tags: apt, dpkg, etc

I've deleted a file in `/etc` provided by package `packageA`. Is there a way that I can reinstall only that file, provided I know where it is and which package provides it?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 on my servers.

Comment: Consider using etckeeper.

Comment: ...or just backup the config files before doing anything to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can find out which package provides the file:

```
dpkg -S /path/to/file
```

Then you can download the current version of the package.

```
apt-get download package-name
```

If for some reason you need the version of the package that you'd initially installed, you'll have to look it up in the APT logs in `/var/log/apt/` or `/var/log/dpkg.log*` (if they haven't aged away). Once you've determined the version number, or the date, you can look for it on [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/) (Debian) or [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu) (Ubuntu).

Once you've downloaded the `.deb` package, you can extract it into a temporary directory with

```
dpkg-deb -x package_name-1.42.deb
```

If you want to print out the content of just one file, you can use

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile package_name-1.42.deb | tar xO ./path/to/file
```

You can copy the content into place, but beware that some files need to have specific permissions. To extract a file with the right permissions, you'll need to extract it as root. You can use `dpkg-deb -x` and then copy the file:

```
# as root
dpkg-deb -x package_name-1.42.deb
cp -p path/to/file /path/to/file
```

Or you can extract the tarball (replace `sudo` by `su` or whatever method you use to gain root):

```
dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile package_name-1.42.deb | sudo tar x -C / ./path/to/file
```

Alternatively, you can reinstall the whole package. If the file is a conffile (i.e. if it's marked as a configuration file to be preserved on upgrades), you'll need instruct dpkg to restore the modified or missing file. It's a little easier to deal with a missing conffile, because you may want to preserve modifications to other conffiles. So if the file is a conffile that you've modified the file and want to restore to its pristine state, rename your version first so that the conffile doesn't exist. Then run

```
dpkg -i --force-confmiss package_name-1.42.deb
```

You can use `apt-get` to download and reinstall the package in one go. If you want to restore a conffile, instruct `apt-get` to pass the extra option to `dpkg`.

```
apt-get --reinstall -o 'DPkg::options="--force-confmiss"' install package_name
```

To avoid this and other difficulties in the future, install [etckeeper](https://joeyh.name/code/etckeeper/) (`apt-get install etckeeper`), edit `/etc/etckeeper/etckeeper.conf` to select your favorite supported version control system, and run `etckeeper init`. Modifications in `/etc` will be saved in version control. Run `etckeeper commit` with a meaningful log message when you change configuration files. Then, if you want to undo a modification in `/etc`, you can restore an old revision of the affected file.

Comment: As always, phenomenal answer.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes. Because /etc mostly contains configuration files, you should be able to download the .deb package, extract the files, and then copy the file to the right directory.

```
mkdir ~/temp
dpkg -x somepackage.deb ~/temp/
cp ~/temp/somefile /etc
```

Whether or not the vanilla file will be configured correctly out of the box is another question.

Comment: @Naftuli: You could also extract the file using a utility like midnight commander (mc).